# Do nuclei with total spins that are whole have bosonic properties? (and nuclei with half total spins fermionic?)

Tags: nuclear-physics

So since the total spin of a nucleus is made up of the underlying spins of the nucleons, you can have whole spins and halve. Bosons have whole spins and follow Bose-Einstein statistics, while fermions have halve spins which follow Fermi-Dirac statistics (and notably the Pauli exclusion principles).

Now I understand that the underlying nucleons have to follow Fermi-Dirac statistics, but I was wondering if there is a slight bosonic characteristic in nuclei of whole spins

Comment: This is stated right in the Wikipedia article on [bosons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson) under the heading composite bosons.